# Android ImageView leaves gaps from edge of screen

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I am trying to make a card game that is played between four players with a standard deck of 52 cards divided equally. I want to display 13 cards on each side of the screen and 4 cards in the middle (these cards will be displayed when each player takes a turn). I have added 13 cards to 4 LinearLayouts each and displayed them on the sides. the two on the right have been rotated (see code).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/table_back1" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/back1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/back1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/back1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/back1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/back1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/back1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/back1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView8"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/back1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView9"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/back1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView10"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/back1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView11"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/back1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView12"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/back1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView13"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/back1_full" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:rotation="180" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ImageView14"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/back1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ImageView15"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/back1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ImageView16"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/back1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ImageView17"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/back1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ImageView18"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/back1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ImageView19"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/back1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ImageView20"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/back1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ImageView21"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/back1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ImageView22"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/back1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ImageView23"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/back1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ImageView24"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/back1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ImageView25"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/back1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ImageView26"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/back1_full" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:rotation="270" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ImageView27"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/back1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ImageView28"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/back1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ImageView29"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/back1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ImageView30"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/back1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ImageView31"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/back1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ImageView32"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/back1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ImageView33"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/back1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ImageView34"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/back1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ImageView35"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/back1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ImageView36"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/back1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ImageView37"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/back1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ImageView38"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/back1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ImageView39"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/back1_full" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:rotation="90" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ImageView40"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/back1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ImageView41"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/back1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ImageView42"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/back1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ImageView43"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/back1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ImageView44"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/back1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ImageView45"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/back1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ImageView46"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/back1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ImageView47"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/back1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ImageView48"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/back1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ImageView49"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/back1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ImageView50"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/back1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ImageView51"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/back1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ImageView52"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/back1_full" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/center1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="false"
             />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/center2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="false"
             />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/center3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="false"
             />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/center4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="false"
             />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**What i have:**

[image]

**What i want:**

The vertical cards to be attached to the edges of the screen as they should be because I set `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"` and `android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"`

**Problems:**

- The cards are in the middle of the screen instead of being attached
  to the sides
- i tried to display 13 cards in a LinearLayout but the cards went
  offscreen on both sides so i had to crop the card and show full cards
  on the edge only.
- The vertical cards start moving towards the edge of the screen each time they are touched.

**Questions:**

- is there a way in which i can stack the cards (overlap) them so they still display the same way without having to crop the picture?
- What is the reason behind the cards not attaching to the edge of the screen?
- Is there a better approach to the solution of this problem?

I have to do this with XML only. Also I'm new to android, so please explain your solution in a way I can understand.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your layout just replacing your image with one of my image and here is my result:

[image: cards]

So I don't understand your result. But if I would like to do what you want with what you have now I would do something like that:

1) top-left top-right:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout4"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"></LinearLayout>
```

2) top-right bottom-left:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout4"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"></LinearLayout>
```

3) bottom-left bottom-right

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout4"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"></LinearLayout>
```

4) top-left bottom-left

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout4"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"></LinearLayout>
```

This is the correct way to do that with LinearLayout, but if you do this, you will realize that it's going out of the border. So you will have to use weight. For exemple if you have 13cards/LinearLayout, you will have to add in your LinearLayout android:android:weightSum="13" and say in each of your card the weight that they have to take, so here 1. (android:layout_weight="1" in each of your card). So it will devide your screen in 13 blocks and one block will be filled with a card. But LinearLayout put his child side by side (that's why I dont understand your result where we can see card one on the other).

So the best way to do this, if you want to put one on the other, is to use a RelativeLayout.

If you want more informations let me know.